# Inconsistent results in symbolic integration with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, version-13.2

I'm encountering a problem with symbolic integration in Mathematica that is giving me inconsistent results even when using assumptions and clearing the variables.

```
$Assumptions = {t > 0, \[Sigma] > 0, g > 0, m > 0, a > 0, p0 > 0};

(*initial state*) \[Psi][x0_] = 
  1/(2 \[Pi] \[Sigma]^2)^(1/4)*Exp[-1/4*x0^2/\[Sigma]^2];
(*evolved state*)\[Psi]t[x_, t_] = (
  E^((m (-12 x^2 + 12 g t x (t - 4 I m \[Sigma]^2) + 
      g^2 t^3 (t - 8 I m \[Sigma]^2)))/(
   24 I t + 48 m \[Sigma]^2)) (2/\[Pi])^(1/4)
    Sqrt[-((I m)/(t \[Sigma]))])/Sqrt[-((2 I m)/t) + 1/\[Sigma]^2];
(*complex conjugate*)\[Psi]tc[x_, t_] = (
  E^((m (-12 x^2 + 12 g t x (t + 4 I m \[Sigma]^2) + 
      g^2 t^3 (t + 8 I m \[Sigma]^2)))/(-24 I t + 
    48 m \[Sigma]^2)) (2/\[Pi])^(1/4) Sqrt[(I m)/(t \[Sigma])])/
  Sqrt[(2 I m)/t + 1/\[Sigma]^2];

d\[Psi]g[x_, t_] = 
  D[\[Psi]t[x, t], g];
d\[Psi]gc[x_, t_] = 
  D[\[Psi]tc[x, t], g];

(*now comes the problematic part*)
\[Alpha] =  
 Integrate[
  d\[Psi]gc[x, t]*d\[Psi]g[x, t], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

The expected result is `1/36 g^2 m^2 t^6 + t^4/(16 \[Sigma]^2) + m^2 t^2 \[Sigma]^2`. However, most of the time, I'm getting a very complicated and lengthy expression involving several GammaRegularized functions. Sometimes I do get the correct result, but it's inconsistent.
[image: Lengthy Result]
In the picture you can see the lengthy result: notice that I've only reported the Integral of the simplified expression of `d\[Psi]gc[x, t]*d\[Psi]g[x, t]`, to show that it is not a problem of definition of the functions.

I have already tried the following approaches to address the issue:

1. Using the `Clear` function to clear the variables before each run.
2. Providing explicit assumptions for the variables involved in the integration, such as `t \[Element] Reals`.
3. Specifying specific ranges of values for the parameters involved in the integration, such as `m>0`, `g>0`, `a>0`, and `\sigma>0`.

Despite these attempts, I'm still facing inconsistent results.

Moreover, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Mathematica but that didn't help. My professor sent me a notebook that performed some of the same calculations and he didn't have any problems on his PC, while I encountered the mentioned errors. He was using Mathematica 13.0, I'm using Mathematica 13.2.

Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to obtain consistent results in this symbolic integration problem? Is there any other approach or technique that can be used to improve the accuracy and consistency of the results? Or any setting I have to change?

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

Comment: You integrate vs `x` and differentiate vs `g`. Is this expected?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes it is. that is not the problem. I just reported it in the question for context.

Comment: Probably there is a syntax error in your last command,  `d\[Psi]gc[x, t]` isn't defined.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I forgot to report it here, I'll edit it now with the corrections. But that is not the problem, as I have both d\[Psi]gc[x, t] and d\[Psi]g[x, t] in my code. Sorry about that

Comment: @GiorgioStucchi I ran it 1000 times and it gave the correct answer (according to you) every single time.

Comment: @1729taxi Thank you. Do you have any clue as to why I'm getting inconsistent results then?

Comment: @Bill Any idea on the reason why I'm getting inconsistent results?

Comment: @Bill Honestly, I have no idea what the changes are that might cause it to work/not work. When it happens, I try different things, like running other (unrelated) cells in between and that sometimes solves the problem. Or sometimes I clear the variables, but neither of these solutions is systematic. One thing I can say: in the question I mentioned my professor's notebook. When he runs it, he has no problems. When I run the SAME notebook, without any modifications, I get the lengthy answer.

Comment: @GiorgioStucchi Since I ran exactly the code you posted - no, I don't see what the problem could be in causing inconsistent results. I kept mine running and it is over 2000 runs and same result every time.

Comment: @Bill What I can tell is that if I kill the kernel, do the calculations without changing anything and repeat the process, this doesn't lead to the same result every time. Sometimes I get the correct one, some others the lengthy wrong one (although it seems to be stuck in "cycles": for example now I only get the lengthy one, earlier only the correct one). BTW, I'm saying the second one is wrong because it's not just a different way of writing the result, it's a totally different expression. Thank you

Comment: @Bill A couple of other hints: just now, with another (similar) integral, I performed the calculation, got the lengthy answer, rerun the same cell immediately and got the correct result. Secondly, as relates to the integral in the question, I run the cell, got the lengthy answer, cleared the variables, rerun the cell and got the correct result (this particular procedure doesn't always work). But at least you know a couple of things I tried which are not random

Comment: Try `$Assumptions={t>0,\[Sigma]>0,g>0,m>0}; Integrate[(result of evaluating dPsig)*(result of evaluating dPsigc),{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]` In other words get rid of all your function definitions, get the results of doing the derivatives, put those inside the Integrate, `a` and `p0` aren't used, get rid of those. Is it still not consistent? Not consistent means it is in the integral. Consistent means it is in the function definitions. Please report back. After that try `$Assumptions-..; FullSimplify[(result of evaluating dPsig)*(result of evaluating dPsigc)]` and paste that inside `Integrate`.

Comment: @Bill I get the lengthy result in both cases. I don't think the problem is not about the definition of the functions or their expression. Moreover, it's possible that if I tried integrating the correct expression (that is FullSimplify[(result of evaluating dPsig)*(result of evaluating dPsigc)]) in an hour or tomorrow I might get the correct result. Finally, I tried opening a new notebook with a new kernel and I just wrote and computed Integrate of the FullSimplify[(result of evaluating dPsig)*(result of evaluating dPsigc)] with the assumpions you gave me and still obtained the lengthy result

Comment: @Bill The fact that asking to integrate the correct expression on a new notebook with a new kernel with the correct assumptions still gives the incorrect result is a good example to explain my problem. everything there is to know is basically there; this example seems to me free from any randomness that might be due to anything else going on in the notebook

Comment: @GiorgioStucchi Since you say it varies randomly, trying it once or twice doesn't seem to be enough. Please try it over and over and over to get more confidence exactly what the smallest change is that turns the bad form on and off. Must find a way to precisely identify what is going on with this.

Comment: @Bill Believe me, I'm trying, but it's impossible to establish a causal relation between what I do and how the program responds. Since evaluating the same cell at the same "stage" of the kernel (I mean first, second or n-th calculation) produces different results, I suspect there is something going on on which I have no control. In particular, now the program gives me yet a different answer, albeit very similar to the correct one. The problem with this one is that there is the subtraction of two Erf with same arguments but written differently, and Mathematica doesn't understand it.

Comment: @Bill Right now I'm working on a notebook with just the assumptions and the integrate of the simplified expression, so there's nothing I can do that justifies the results being different for each run of the cell. I'm also restarting the kernel each time, so I really believe that it's not a problem related to what I'm doing

Comment: I recommend that you do some intermediate simplifications to simplify the integrand before the integration step. The different (presumably) equivalent forms may result from an internal step in the integration timing out (depending on overall load on the processor(s)) and giving different forms to the next step. In any event, I would always recommend considering simplifying an integrand before doing the integration.

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you, but the problem of obtaining different results for different runs of the same cell persists even when using the simplified form